# Why there is no tournament scene in Mortal Kombat (2021)?

Tags: mortal-kombat

If there is a dialog on a tournament:

> Tsung: The prophecy is upon us, which means we could lose the tenth **tournament**.

Why there is no tournament scene in *Mortal Kombat* (2021)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Mortal Kombat’s director explains why there’s no tournament scene in *Mortal Kombat (2021)*](https://variety.com/2021/film/features/mortal-kombat-sequel-ending-deaths-johnny-cage-1234955355/)

> **Despite being titled “Mortal Kombat,” the characters don’t actually fight in a Mortal Kombat tournament, possibly saving it for the future. Was that always the plan?** 
> "The story came out of this idea that we didn’t just want to redo the first film. If you look at “Mortal Kombat’s” evolution over the decades, that has evolved and grown beyond the idea of the tournament. That’s obviously essential within the DNA of “Mortal Kombat,” and it’s one of the fundamentals, if you look at where the story has gone. The idea of a tournament within a script informs a certain structure and rhythm. We didn’t really want to serve that. To serve a tournament idea, you have to build it a certain way. So it was a couple of reasons that came to it playing out in the way it did."